# Delete pattern of names from files

Tags: rename, filename, youtube-dl

I downloaded some files with youtube-dl.
The name is always like this

```
foo - baar -PSUHDUWHDAIHDWU.ogg/mp3/...
```

How can I remove this random letters (cut the last '-*') at the end from all files of a folder so that the name is:

```
foo - baar.mp3/ogg/...
```

I tried something with "rename" but I have no idead, what pattern to use. I think it should be something like this: "*#*-*"

Comment: What are the full names of the files ? GIve some examples..

Comment: Are they always in the same format ? foo *space* - *space* baar ?

Comment: Ton Steine Scherben - Alles verändert sich-3CUz4M3M1r8.ogg
Ton Steine Scherben - Der Traum ist aus-WYZCovq71XE.ogg
Ton Steine Scherben - Feierabend-BopYtPtjlkI.ogg
Ton Steine Scherben - Ich will nicht werden, was mein Alter ist-WpLfJZvnWSw.ogg
Ton Steine Scherben - Keine Macht für Niemand-XtMPGhXnzWE.ogg
Ton Steine Scherben - Komm schlaf bei mir-Nr9V_UH04eA.ogg

Comment: posted an answer, please review

Comment: So, you want to change '-[A-Z]+.ogg$' to '.ogg'? Try something like `find . -type f -name '*.ogg' -print0 | xargs -0 rename -v -n 's/-[A-Z]+.ogg$/.ogg/'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `rename`, assuming that a `.` only appears at the end of the filename for the extension, you can use the following expression:

```
s/-[^-]*\././
```

This replaces a hyphen followed by characters other than a hyphen until a `.`, with `.`, effectively deleting the last hyphen and the characters following it. Use it thus:

```
rename -n 's/-[^-]*\././' *
```

If the changed names look fine, then run without `-n`.

Comment: muru, i think OP has asked to append a `.mp3` too..

Comment: @heemayl I'm pretty sure `ogg/mp3/...` indicates that extensions may vary.

Comment: ummm...ok ....then i need to modify my one :)

Answer (score 2):

Instead of hacking with replacing pattern you can just tell youtube-dl not to include these random letters (that's a video id actually) to the final filename. This can be done with [output template](https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl#output-template), e.g. `youtube-dl -o "%(title)s.%(ext)s" 3CUz4M3M1r8` will result in `Ton Steine Scherben - Alles verndert sich.mp4`.

Comment: thanks a lot! :) this is the easiest way
is this also usable for playlists?

Comment: Absolutely. With output template it's also possible to specify arbitrary hierachies, e.g. to put all playlist videos in separated directory inside your home directory `-o "~/%(playlist)s/%(title)s.%(ext)s"`.

Answer (score 1):

Using `bash` parameter expansion:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
shopt -s extglob
for file in *(*mp3|*ogg); do
    ini="${file%-*}"
    ext="${file##*.}"
    mv "$file" "${ini}.${ext}"
done
```

- Here we have used the `extglob` and parameter expansion feature of `bash`.
- `ini` will contain the initial portion discarding the portion from last `-` onwards
- `ext` will contain the extension e.g. `ogg`, `mp3`

**Test :**

```bsh
$ ls
scr.sh                                                      Ton Steine Scherben - Ich will nicht werden, was mein Alter ist-WpLfJZvnWSw.ogg
Ton Steine Scherben - Alles verändert sich-3CUz4M3M1r8.ogg  Ton Steine Scherben - Keine Macht für Niemand-XtMPGhXnzWE.mp3
Ton Steine Scherben - Der Traum ist aus-WYZCovq71XE.ogg     Ton Steine Scherben - Komm schlaf bei mir-Nr9V_UH04eA.mp3
Ton Steine Scherben - Feierabend-BopYtPtjlkI.ogg

$ bash scr.sh 

$ ls
scr.sh                                          Ton Steine Scherben - Ich will nicht werden, was mein Alter ist.ogg
Ton Steine Scherben - Alles verändert sich.ogg  Ton Steine Scherben - Keine Macht für Niemand.mp3
Ton Steine Scherben - Der Traum ist aus.ogg     Ton Steine Scherben - Komm schlaf bei mir.mp3
Ton Steine Scherben - Feierabend.ogg
```

Comment: Isn't this renaming .ogg files to .mp3? That might not be too good...

Comment: @Stunts Yeah..i got it wrong..i will edit

Answer (score 0):

**Script**

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
# Author : Serg Kolo
# Description: script for renaming files 
# for http://askubuntu.com/q/626258/295286

for file in *; do

        FILENAME=$( awk -F '-' '{gsub(" ","");print $1"-"$2}' <<< "$file")
        EXTENSION=$( awk -F '.' '{print $2}' <<< "$file")
        mv "$file" ./"$FILENAME.$EXTENSION"

done
```

**Results**

[image]

Comment: Just curious: why this roundabout way of printing the filename ... from the filename?

Comment: @muru I'll explain later in the chat but I guess it could be edited to echo "$ file"

Answer (score 0):

Based on the pattern you provide, you can try this:

`perl-rename "s/\-[a-zA-Z0-9]*\././g" *`

It uses a perl regexp to replace any uppercase letters after a "-" and before a "." with just a "." in any file. the final "*" tells the command to include all the files in the current dir.

It has to be run inside the dir you have your files.